# Default credentials for confluent schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

If I'm running Confluent platform locally, what would be the default credentials to access schema registry? I am not using Confluent Cloud. Running all services locally using `confluent local services start`. I haven't modified any of the default configs in `/etc/**`.

```
$: confluent schema-registry schema list --schema-registry-endpoint http://localhost:8081

Error: you must log in to use this command

Suggestions:
    Log in with `confluent login`.
    If you need a Confluent Cloud account, sign up with `confluent cloud-signup`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no credentials when running `confluent local`.

But if there were, you'd start by inspecting your `schema-registry.properties` file, or if the server is started with a JAAS file (look at the running Java process arguments for the Registry)

As far as I know, `confluent schema-registry` requires connecting to Confluent Cloud.

Just use tools like Postman / Insomnia locally

Comment: Yes, that's what I realized when I further dug into this. I only hope that their documentation made it clear. I can use Postman / Insomnia / curl to invoke the schema registry APIs directly and it works with no issues.

Comment: Last I checked, the documentation for `confluent schema-registry` does say this command is only to operate with Confluent Cloud Registry

Comment: As you can see, the documentation has references to both Cloud and On-Premises. https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/schema-registry/index.html. The `schema list` command is valid for On-Premises.

Comment: I see. At the bottom of the page, there's a "give us feedback" button you can use report an issue